# Slick 3.0.0 Warning when using Update

Tags: scala, slick

I have a simple update that tries to update two columns for a particular row. Here is what I do: (I'm using Scala 2.11.7)

```
val update =
  (id: Long, state: MyState) =>
    myTable.filter(_.id === id)
      .map(tbl =>(tbl.name, tbl.updateDate))
      .update(state.name, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

Here is what my compiler tells me:

```
[warn] /Users/joe/vpp-projects/app/my/project/services/database/MySchema.scala:40: Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.
[warn]         signature: UpdateActionExtensionMethodsImpl.update(value: T): JdbcActionComponent.this.DriverAction[Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write]
[warn]   given arguments: state.name, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)
[warn]  after adaptation: UpdateActionExtensionMethodsImpl.update((state.name, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)): (String, org.joda.time.DateTime))
[warn]           .update(state.name, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
[warn]          

    ^
```

Any clues as to what is happening here? I do not get the Warnings to be of any use to me so that I could get rid of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` takes a `Tuple` - scala has a feature that will convert a method call with multiple arguments into a tuple if there is no method that takes the multiple arguments:

```
def anExample(value: (Int, Int, String)): Int = value._3.length

// This is how it is properly called
anExample((1, 2, "hi"))

// But this also works
anExample(1, 2, "hi")
```

You can either:

- Update your call

  ```
  // Note the added tuple parenthesis
  .update((state.name, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)))
  ```
- Add `-Yno-adapted-args` to your `scalacOptions` to remove the warning completely:

  ```
  // If using SBT
  scalacOptions in Compile += "-Yno-adapted-args"
  ```